# Woocommerce: Display add to cart buttons on certain category pages only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have some great code in my functions.php file which puts an "add to cart" button underneath the products in the main shop page. This is it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
```

That's great! But I'm now changing some products to variable products and it says "select options" underneath instead.

Can I alter this code so that it only displays on a page showing products from certain categories?

In other words, the main shop page has the variable products (no add to cart buttons), but I also have category pages showing simple products which display the add to cart buttons as per the code above.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would remove the action from specific product categories using a conditional tag as its already displayed by default.

```
is_product_category()
```

Make sure you use a hook which fires before its added.